# Delete a specific amount of text until it finds an open paragraph

Tags: vba, text, ms-word

I am looking to create a macro that allows me to delete a specific amount of text until it finds an open paragraph. For example:

```
gateways (...)
ABC
DEF
GHJ
IKL

Other
```

I want to delete by searching the word "gateways" and then delete all text until it finds the line before "Other". The problem is that the amount of text until "other" is variable from document to document, and I cannot find a macro that allows me to do that wothout errors.

Comment: can your "paragraphs" be defined as "\n\n+" in RegEx?

Answer (score 0):

To delete the text Gateway down to the empty line, leaving only Other

```
Public Sub DeleteFromTextToEmptyLine()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "gateways"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    'find text
    If Selection.Find.Execute() Then
        'Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'remove comment to leave the word gateway intact
        'Turn on Extended select mode
        Selection.ExtendMode = True
        'find two paragraph marks together, i.e. empty line
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "^p^p"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        'if found, delete the selection
        If Selection.Find.Execute() Then Selection.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to leave the word gateway, remove the comment from the indicated line